# how to share modules in play framework 2

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt

I am trying to build 2 website which use the same core functionality using play framework 2 (JAVA). the challenge is how to set up the project so the core part can be shared between the 2 projects. In play 1 we could have a common module and pool it in by the application but I could not find a way to do this using play 2. I understand that I can create a module directory and put the core code there but this would not be an ideal solution for me since the code in the module need to be shared with multiple projects. anyone has any idea how to solve this problem??

so far I tried to get around with the problem by creating one project with 3 modules, one the core module and the other ones are the websites.

```
-mainProject
      -modules
           -core
           -website1
           -website2
```

but the problem is that I cannot call the functions in the core from the code inside the other modules. plus inconveniently i am keeping multiple build files and route files and depending on what website i want to build, I rename them.

please note that the core needs to have its own routes and actions in the controllers.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Play has multi-module support built right in, but you might be able to hack together a solution using Maven on top of Play.

What you could do it to make 3 different Play projects, one each for Core, Website1 and Website2. Since you need to "export" the core project, you can use Maven to do that.

In the Core project, you create a pom.xml (a Maven build file) that can [package the Core project as a JAR](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html). You then run [mvn install:install](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html) to install the core JAR in your local repository, which you can then use in your other website projects.
(Side note, there's a [Maven-Play bridge here](https://code.google.com/p/play2-maven-plugin/wiki/Rationale) that you might find useful)

Now, in your Website1 and Website2 Play projects, you'll add a [dependency](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/SBTDependencies) to this JAR in your Build.scala file. You add it to the appDependencies

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
    "your-core-project-artifact-name" % "your-core-project-project-name" % "1.0.0.0",
    "javax.mail" % "mail" % "1.4" // Existing libraries
)
```

Finally, add your local repository (where the core project is being installed) as a resolver in your Website1 and Website2 projects

```
resolvers += (
    "Local Maven Repository" at "file://"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository"
)
```

There you have it. When you build your Website1/Website2 projects, Play should add the dependency to your Core project, and you'll be able to call into methods from your Core project from your website projects

Comment: This is conceptually the way to go about things if you have a fully-fledged  Play project that you want to reuse across your other websites. However you don't have to introduce Maven. You can run the `publish-local` task from `core` to publish it to your local Play repository. You can then just list it as a dependency in your website projects as above without needing to add another repository.

Comment: As a follow-up comment, I have tried doing this in the past with no success. A problem I hit was with the loading of the routes files. With this setup you have a main website app with a `routes` file, and a core JAR with another `routes` file. I found that my core routes would trump my website routes when launching my website project, and would thus be the only routes available for my site. I was however working in Play 2.0 at the time, and it's possible that there's a way around this in Play 2.1.

Comment: @avik, thanks, in your proposed solution, the module would be a completely separate play module or would it go under module directory inside the project?

Comment: @nightograph - as mentioned in @PowerPanda's answer, `core`, `website1` and `website2` are completely separate Play projects.